# Python endswith() function, without the built-in function

Tags: python, function, ends-with

I need to make the endswith() function without using the built-in function in Python. I wanted to know if there is any way i could do it shorter and easier? I'm sure there is, my way is really complicated.

```
string = "example for endswith"

find = "endswith"

l = len(find)

final = False

b = 0
tstring =[]
new = "" 
for i in string:
    if find[b] == i:
        tstring.insert(b,i)
        b = b + 1
        if b == l:
            print(tstring)
            break
for x in tstring: 
        new += x

print(new)

if(new==find):
    final = True

print(final)
```

Comment: please include your code on this site (there is a formating option: {}) and don't link to external sites

Comment: Please include your code and all relevant information as **text** in your question, not as images.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please complete your [tour] and see [ask], and [edit] your question with your codes directly within the question body.

Comment: Sentences like "It works, but i need a shorter and better one." are an indicator that your question would probably be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com ;>

Comment: I'm new to the site sorry, there i edited it.

Comment: So my code works, but i was wondering if there is any easier and more simple way of doing it, which i am sure there is.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
def endswith(a, b):
  for i in range(len(b)):
    if a[-1-i] != b[-1-i]:
      return False
  return True
```

Here's a recursive implementation, not useful, just for educational purposes:

```
def endswith(a, b):
  return not b or (b[-1] == a[-1] and endswith(a[:-1], b[:-1]))
```

Or, of course, without a loop:

```
def endswith(a, b):
  return a[-len(b):] == b
```

But I think that wasn't the idea of the task.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  There's no need to leave thank-you comments.  Just upvote an answer when it helped you (upwards triangle left of the answer, that's the simpler equivalent of a thank-you) and/or accept it (checkmark) if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```py
string = "example for endswith"

find = "endswith"

l = len(find)

final = False

print(find[::-1] == string[::-1][:l])
```

Comment: I recommend not using variables names `l`, `O` or `I`.  depending on the font they look a lot like `1`, `0` and `l` and can lead to a lot of confusion.

Comment: I second Alfe's comment. Generally speaking, try not to use single letter variable names

Comment: Please describe, what did you change and why, to help others understand the problem and this answer